# React Native Watchman not installed

Tags: react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, watchman

I am using this cmd

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
$ cd watchman
$ git checkout v4.9.0  # the latest stable release
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

When I enter make cmd its return error like below

```
Makefile:1960: recipe for target 'cppclient/libwatchmanclient_la-WatchmanClient.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [cppclient/libwatchmanclient_la-WatchmanClient.lo] 
Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/watchman'
Makefile:1101: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your build is picking up some version of `folly` from your system.
Use `./configure --without-folly` to configure the build.

Comment: Hi thanks for your replay ! 
Its not working for me error still exits

Comment: Makefile:1960: recipe for target 'cppclient/libwatchmanclient_la-WatchmanClient.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [cppclient/libwatchmanclient_la-WatchmanClient.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/palanisamy/watchman'
Makefile:1101: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2